# Error when Multiple JOINS are used

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute the following query, Bu it gives a syntax error, Can some point me were the problem is?

```
select count(*) from (((
 select * from testlink1915.TL_tcversions where execution_type = 2 and id = 66134) c 
 JOIN (select * from testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy) d 
   ON id = testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy.parent_id) a 
 JOIN (select * FROM testlink1915.TL_req_coverage where req_id = 67635) b 
   ON a.id = b.testcase_id);
```

Error appeared only when I added the following segment.

```
c JOIN (select * from testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy) d 
  ON id = testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy.parent_id
```

The error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a JOIN (select * FROM testlink1915.TL_req_coverage where req_id = 67635) b ON a.' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
c.id = d.parent_id
```

instead of

```
id = testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy.parent_id
```

Try this:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select * 
    from (
        select * 
        from (
            select *
            from testlink1915.TL_tcversions
            where execution_type = 2
                and id = 66134
            ) c join (
            select *
            from testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy
            ) d on c.id = d.parent_id
        ) a join (
        select *
        from testlink1915.TL_req_coverage
        where req_id = 67635
        ) b on a.id = b.testcase_id
    ) t;
```

Please note that I use `*` everywhere. Replace it with the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still get the same error, when I remove "c join (
            select *
            from testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy
            ) d on c.id = d.parent_id" It starts to work. Anything elsse I'm missing here?

Comment: U need to add a alias to the roor select statement. Then it worked, Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
select count(1) from
  (
  select * from (
  select * from testlink1915.TL_tcversions where execution_type = 2 and id = 66134 ) c
  JOIN
  (select * from testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy) d on a.id=d.parent_id
  join 
  (select * FROM testlink1915.TL_req_coverage where req_id = 67635) a  ON a.id = b.testcase_id

  ) as E join (select * from testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy) F  ON E.id = F.parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below query :

select count(*) from 
(
  (
    select * from testlink1915.TL_tcversions 
    JOIN testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy ON id =
    testlink1915.TL_nodes_heirachy.parent_id where execution_type = 2 and id   
    = 66134
   ) a
 JOIN
   (
     select * FROM testlink1915.TL_req_coverage where req_id = 67635
   )   ON a.id = b.testcase_id 
) ;
```